# Is list's variable is an object in Python?

Tags: python

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]
```

I understand `a is b` is false but i can't understand `a is [1,2,3]` is false

I learned variable is like nickname for objects like `x = 2` and `id(x) == id(2)`

but `id(a)` is not as same as `id(b)`...

In this case, a is an object? not a variable?

Comment: One source of confusion might be that cpython has some internal optimizations for small constant integers. Instead of `2`, try using `20000`.

Comment: In addition to the suggested post above, check out these related posts on the subject: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961231/why-do-strings-with-the-same-value-refer-to-the-same-object-but-lists-dont?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189660/two-variables-in-python-have-same-id-but-not-lists-or-tuples/38189759#38189759).

Answer (score 1):

Variables are references to objects. `a` does not reference the same object as `b`. Even though the two objects are the same they have unique addresses in memory and do not depend on each other.

```
>>> a = b = [1,2,3]
>>> c = [1,2,3]
>>> print(a is b)
True
>>> print(a is c or b is c)
False
>>> a.remove(1)
>>> print(a)
[2, 3]
>>> print(b)
[2, 3]
>>> print(c)
[1, 2, 3]
```

In the case of the `x = 2` and `id(x) == id(2)` integers are immutable and in CPython `id` is simply the location of an object in memory. Integers are always the same so storing the same integer several times at different addresses would be a waste of memory.

However, in general DO NOT use integers with `is` operator as it can lead to different results across different python implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Python is an object. `a is b` evaluates to false because, as you know, they are not the same object. They are both instances of the `List` class, therefore having different locations in memory, and being completely separate in every way except their class structure, or blueprint, as you can think of it. `id(a)` and `id(b)` will reflect this, they are not the same object and will therefore not share an ID. This is a reference to their location in memory, and while IDs are *not* referenced pointers, they are similar in that they describe their not being the same.

```py
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
>>> # the below is an example, every session will result in a different ID,
>>> # as it's being stored at a unique mem location each time
>>> id(a)
2770873780160
>>> id(b)
2770873412800
>>> id(a) - id(b)  # simply to show the difference in location.
367360
```

[double equals vs is in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008380/double-equals-vs-is-in-python)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-and-is-operator-in-python